# Populating SwiftUI ViewBuilder function parameter with protocol function

Tags: swiftui

I'm not sure if this is possible, but I'm trying to use a protocol function to populate the `actions` parameter of an `.alert` modifier in SwiftUI, and I can't figure out exactly how to do it correctly.

The code I'm trying goes like this:

```swift
protocol ErrorWithActions: Error {
    func alertActions<V: View>() -> V
}

struct MyView: View {
    @State var isShowingError = false
    var theError: ErrorWithActions? = nil

    var body: some View {
        Text("Blah blah blah")
            .alert(
                "An Error Occurred",
                isPresented: $isShowingError,
                presenting: theError,
                actions: { $0.alertActions() } // Compile error here
            )
    }
}
```

This won't compile because the `actions: { $0.alertActions() }` line fails with the compiler error `Generic parameter 'Content' could not be inferred`.

I think I understand that this doesn't work because `.alert`'s ViewBuilder parameters need to know at compile time what the resulting view will be, and the protocol implementation can't supply that (without the protocol having an associatedtype for its view output, but that would require all cases of an enum implementing the protocol to return the same set of actions, which defeats the purpose of the protocol function).

I implemented a workaround that seems to work, where instead of `alertActions()` returning a view, it returns an array of `AlertAction`, a struct that can be translated into the buttons used in the alert, but it would be really nice if I could just supply the buttons directly. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: You are never going to be able to use a `Protocol` in place of a `View` struct as a it is never an unsubstantiated object. From [Swift.org](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/documentation/the-swift-programming-language/protocols/), "A protocol defines a blueprint of methods, properties, and other requirements that suit a particular task or piece of functionality. The protocol can then be adopted by a class, structure, or enumeration to provide an actual implementation of those requirements. Any type that satisfies the requirements of a protocol is said to conform to that protocol."

Comment: Oh well. As I suspected. I guess I’ll stick with the workaround. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `AnyView` instead of making it through generics.

This will work:

```swift
protocol ErrorWithActions: Error {
    func alertActions() -> AnyView
}
```

Also, it's unrelated, but instead of `@Published` you are meant to use `@State` for `isShowingError`

Comment: Thank you! `AnyView` that did the trick perfectly (just have to remember to wrap any return value in `AnyView(...)`, but that's easy enough). And you're right about the `@Published`. I copied that wrong from my code. Fixed now.

Comment: `AnyView` has performance implications and is generally _not_ something you want to rely on much. Watch Demystify SwiftUI from WWDC for information about why.

Comment: Apple does indeed recommend to avoid `AnyView` as it erases structural identification and makes the view to rebuild if there are any changes. However, in this specific case, I wouldn't expect actions for the error to be very dynamic and be observing any state changes, so it should be acceptable here.